# Android SearchRecentSuggestions - suggestions do not get displayed when typing in SearchView

Tags: java, android, search, search-suggestion

I have a working search widget and want to add search history suggestions. I followed the Android tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html), and while the search still works, no suggestions are being displayed. Here is my code:

1. Content provider

   ```
   package com.mypackage;

   import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;

   public class SearchHistoryProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
       public final static String AUTHORITY = SearchHistoryProvider.class.getName();
       public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

       public SearchHistoryProvider() {
           setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Declaring provider in Manifest

   ```
   <provider 
       android:name=".SearchHistoryProvider"
       android:authorities="com.mypackage.SearchHistoryProvider">
   </provider>
   ```
3. Searchable configuration

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:hint="@string/search_hint"
       android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
       android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.mypackage.SearchHistoryProvider"
       android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?">
   </searchable>
   ```
4. Saving the queries to the content provider (in my searchable Activity)

   ```
   private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
   if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

       String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
       SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                           SearchHistoryProvider.AUTHORITY, SearchHistoryProvider.MODE);
       suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);

       // Collapse the search view as a search is performed
       MenuItem searchItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.search);
       SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mMenu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
       searchItem.collapseActionView();
       searchView.setQuery("", false);

       // send the query to the global search activity for loading the data
       Intent globalSearchIntent = new Intent(this, GlobalSearchFragmentActivity.class);
       GroceryOTGUtils.copyIntentData(intent, globalSearchIntent);
       globalSearchIntent.putExtra(GlobalSearchFragmentActivity.GLOBAL_SEARCH, true);
       startActivity(globalSearchIntent);
   }
   }
   ```

Everything works fine, except the suggestions do not actually show up (the search looks the same as before I added them). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I solved the issue. It was a mistake in the Android manifest configuration (the provider's name). How can I remove the bounty?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad if you put the bounty for others question you can't remove bounty !

Comment: @Eng.Fouad moderator can refund the bounty in extreme cases, you can try and flag this post, choose "Other" and pledge your case. Still not too late. :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Can you briefly describe your resolution in an answer such that it can be helpful to others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem was, that the declaration of the SearchHistoryProvider
in the Manifest.xml was wrong.

```
android:name=".SearchHistoryProvider"
```

Writing .$NAME is a shorthand for 
$DEFAULTPACKAGE.$NAME, so if your $DEFAULTPACKAGE is 'com.myapp'
und you write .SearchHistoryProvider as the android:name of your 
Provider, Android will simply not find it, as it is located in
com.mypackage, as the first line of the following code indicates.

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;

public class SearchHistoryProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = SearchHistoryProvider.class.getName();
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public SearchHistoryProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
}
```