# Making an Android TV app searchable (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv, android-search

I am trying to make my app searchable, according to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable.html). However, it does not work.

I tried [the sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) (which is the source of the code in the documentation) and it works just fine. But when I tried to create a simple app from scratch using the tutorial, I was not able to get it to work.

I have browsed the most popular answers on SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240057/android-searchrecentsuggestions-suggestions-do-not-get-displayed-when-typing-i) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497514/content-provider-query-not-being-called-android-tv). Still no luck :-(

There is this part in the Manifest.xml of the sample that looks a bit suspicious

```
<path-permission 
    android:pathPrefix="/search" 
    android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
```

but I am not sure what to make of it...

Does anybody have experience with this? Is there some super-common pitfall I could be falling into?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was REALLY annoying to track...

I created my `ContentProvider` implementation in Kotlin, instead of Java. Turns out that if I run the very same logic written in Java, it works perfectly fine.

I have no time or will to go into the details, but I would guess that one of the overriden methods has a non-null param, gets a null there form the system, an exception gets thrown and the `ContentProvider` is silently killed.

So **if you your `ContentProvider` is in Kotlin and does not work, convert it to Java and try again.**